# How to set component to be always on top Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an ArrowBlock component and it sometimes appears in the same position as other image but it goes under it. I would like to keep this ArrowBlock to be drawn always on top.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the [Canvas.ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980110%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to a value higher than all the other components in the same container (works for other containers besides `Canvas` despite the name).